# "mysqli_insert_id" Not Generated after using "Prepare Statement"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm try to generate `singer id` after inserting data in another table,
when i'm using prepare statement the problem occur:

> Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object > given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/singer.php on > line 22 Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: Couldn't fetch > mysqli in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/singer.php on > line 24

```
<?php
include('../db_inc.php');    
$singer_name =$_POST['singer_name'];
$singer_gender=$_POST['singer_gender'];
$singer_des=$_POST['singer_description'];
$singer_genre=$_POST['genre_list'];

        if($stmt=$connection->prepare("INSERT INTO singers(singer_name,singer_gender,singer_description) VALUES (?,?,?)")){
            $stmt->bind_param('sss',$singer_name,$singer_gender,$singer_des);
            $result1=$stmt -> execute();
            $singer_id=mysqli_insert_id($stmt);
            $stmt->close();
            }

  if($stmt2=$connection->prepare("INSERT INTO genre_singer(f_singer_id,f_genre_id) VALUES (?,?)")){
      $stmt2->bind_param('fs',$singer_id,$singer_genre);
            $result2=$stmt2 -> execute();
            $stmt2->close();
            $connection->close();
      }
if($result1 & $result2){
    echo "insert successfully"; 
    };
?>
```

Comment: You already have been told in the error message what the problem is, "mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given"... what's wrong with reading that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
$singer_id=mysqli_insert_id($stmt);
```

to:

```
$singer_id=mysqli_insert_id($connection);
```

Answer (score 7):

You are not using `mysqli_insert_id` correctly.  It should be:

```
mysqli_insert_id($connection);
```

Or better yet:

```
$connection->insert_id
```

See the docs: http://php.net/mysqli_insert_id